# Cross compiling python for ARM from source

Tags: python, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I am cross compiling python 3.7 for ARM using TI-SDK.

I have downloaded the source code on ubuntu and followed the below instructions

1. Set the path of SDK (export PATH = $PATH:)
2. ./confgure
3. make

When I run `make`, I get the errors below. Can you please tell me how to resolve the linker errors?

```
*ar rc libpython3.5m.a Modules/config.o Modules/getpath.o Modules/main.o Modules/gcmodule.o 
ar rc libpython3.5m.a Modules/_threadmodule.o  Modules/signalmodule.o  Modules/posixmodule.o  Modules/errnomodule.o  Modules/pwdmodule.o  Modules/_sre.o  Modules/_codecsmodule.o  Modules/_weakref.o  Modules/_functoolsmodule.o  Modules/_operator.o  Modules/_collectionsmodule.o  Modules/itertoolsmodule.o  Modules/atexitmodule.o  Modules/_stat.o  Modules/timemodule.o  Modules/_localemodule.o  Modules/_iomodule.o Modules/iobase.o Modules/fileio.o Modules/bytesio.o Modules/bufferedio.o Modules/textio.o Modules/stringio.o  Modules/zipimport.o  Modules/faulthandler.o  Modules/_tracemalloc.o Modules/hashtable.o  Modules/symtablemodule.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o
ranlib libpython3.5m.a
gcc -pthread   -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python Programs/python.o libpython3.5m.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil   -lm  
libpython3.5m.a(fileutils.o): In function `set_inheritable':
/home/pcadmin/work/OTIS/Python-3.5.9/Python/fileutils.c:892: undefined reference to `fcntl64'
/home/pcadmin/work/OTIS/Python-3.5.9/Python/fileutils.c:903: undefined reference to `fcntl64'
libpython3.5m.a(fileutils.o): In function `get_inheritable':
/home/pcadmin/work/OTIS/Python-3.5.9/Python/fileutils.c:777: undefined reference to `fcntl64'
/home/pcadmin/work/OTIS/Python-3.5.9/Python/fileutils.c:777: undefined reference to `fcntl64'
libpython3.5m.a(fileutils.o): In function `set_inheritable':
/home/pcadmin/work/OTIS/Python-3.5.9/Python/fileutils.c:892: undefined reference to `fcntl64'
libpython3.5m.a(fileutils.o):/home/pcadmin/work/OTIS/Python-3.5.9/Python/fileutils.c:903: more undefined references to `fcntl64' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:555: recipe for target 'python' failed
make: *** [python] Error 1*
```

Please comment if more information is required to help me out with this issue.

Comment: So, why not to simple use Buildroot distribution altogether?

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution. Thought it may help others if i post it.

The linker error is due to the dependency on libxml2. I have cross compiled libxml2 and linked to python and it worked.

The configure script includes the path of libxml along with other options.

```
 ./configure CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar LD=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm -prefix=/home/sagar/otis/python3_install --without-sqlite3 --without-pdo-sqlite --without-pear --enable-simplexml --disable-mbregex --enable-sockets --enable-fpm --disable-opcache --enable-libxml --without-zlib --with-libxml-dir=/home/sagar/otis/libxml/_install/ --build=x86_64-linux-gnu  --disable-all --disable-ipv6 ac_cv_have_long_long_format=yes ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no
```